# Microsoft Access SQL Transform-Pivot table (getting results)

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transform

From this SQL

```
SELECT Objetos.NReg, Objetos.Type, Objetos.Date, Campos.Text, Contenido.Value
FROM (Campos LEFT JOIN Contenido ON Campos.Id = Contenido.Id_Campo) LEFT JOIN Objetos ON Contenido.Id_Objeto = Objetos.Id
GROUP BY Objetos.NReg, Objetos.Type, Objetos.Date, Campos.Text, Contenido.Value, Campos.Id
ORDER BY Objetos.NReg, Campos.Id;
```

I have a table like this:

```
NRegType    Date    Text        Value
                    Year    
001 1               Title       Diccionario
001 1               Title       Traducir
001 1               Subtitle    Español-Ingles
002 1               Title       Diccionario
002 1               Subtitle    Inglés-Español
002 1               Editorial   Hispanoamericana
```

**I want to be display like this:**

```
NRegType    Date    Title.1     Title.2     SubTitle        Editorial       Year
001 1               Diccionario Traducir    Español-Ingles
002 2               Diccionario             Inglés-Español  Hispanoamericana
```

The more I´ve got was

```
TRANSFORM Min(Contenido.Value) AS VALORDE
SELECT Objetos.NReg, Objetos.Type, Objetos.Date
FROM Fields LEFT JOIN (Contenido LEFT JOIN Objetos ON Contenido.Id_Objeto = Objetos.Id)  ON Campos.Id = Contenido.Id_Campo
GROUP BY Objetos.NReg, Objetos.Type, Objetos.Date
PIVOT Campos.Text;

NRegType    Date    Year    Editorial           Subtitle            Title

001 1                                           Español-Ingles      Diccionario
002 1                       Hispanoamericana    Inglés-Español      Diccionario
```

With 1 empty field above. Is this possible?
I couldn´t get the repited field Title value, and also can´t order the fields the way I want.
The Table Campos is

```
Id  Texto
1   Title
2   Subtitle
3   Editorial
4   Year
```

The table Contenidos is:

```
Id  Id_Objeto   Id_Campo    Value
1   1           1           Diccionario
2   1           2           Español-Ingles
3   2           1           Diccionario
4   2           2           Inglés-Español
5   2           3           Hispanoamericana
6   1           1           Traducir
```

And Objetos is:

```
Id  NReg    Type    Date
1   001     1       
2   002     1
```

Just don´t know if what I want can be done...